# Javascript Regex Replace Exact character

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have this code

```
htmlString= htmlString.replace( new RegExp( "WW(.+?)WW", "gim" ),
    "<span style='color:red;border-bottom:1px dashed red;'>$1</span>" );
```

This seems to work however it is replacing the www's in url's.  What I have is WW somestring WW I clip out the text between WW and replace it. However, I can't seem to only get the exact char sequence. I tried {WW} ^WW [^WW] with the end [$WW] and variations. Also tried \bWW string \bWW and no match.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Give more examples of what you are trying to replace.

Comment: Wouldn't a [regex literal](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.5) look better?

Comment: Sample string = PHysell WW **3 miles Northwest Christiansburg, va** WW Pea size hail

Comment: WW ---- WW is the designator that there is some location in between. Could be named location, state, zipcode, intersection, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that there is something else than alphanumeric characters after the starting `WW` and before the ending `WW` (whitespace, for example), then you could do this:

```
htmlString = htmlString.replace(/\bWW\b\s*(.+?)\s*\bWW\b/g, 
    "<span style='color:red;border-bottom:1px dashed red;'>$1</span>" );
```

Using a regex object instead of a string literal makes it easier to read. If you had used `\b` in a string literal it would have meant "backspace" - you need to escape backslashes in a string literal, so the above regex would become `"\\bWW\\b\\s*(.+?)\\s*\\bWW\\b"`.

Comment: BAM thanks, that does look better. I tried the \b but didn't add the / to the beginning or something. I will get the hang of this regex someday. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If the text you're looking to replace is always uppercase and the www you don't want to replace is always lowercase, then you can just replace the `"gim"` with `"gm"`: the `i` indicates ignore case.  The `m` in `"gim"` has no meaning in a RegExp so you can reduce to `"g"`.

Comment: Well I cant assume it will always be upper or lowercase. Should be upper but users make errors. However that would be a quick fix in the mean time, thanks.

Comment: What about the spaces on either side of 'WW'... are those required?  If so, your search can be `" WW (.+?) WW "` and you can ignore case.